# Patent Prosecution - SEQ ID NO

Tags: patent-applications, prosecution

When drafting patent applications, can we skip certain numbers from the SEQ ID NOs? (This is just for convenience, so that I don't have to go back and renumber everything.) for US/PCT/worldwide, generally.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you referring to figure numbers or references numbers  to specific items within a figure ?

Answer (score 0):

*If* you are talking about reference numbers there is no requirement for monotonically increasing values.  Often you will see ref. numbers that are not numbers- like 100B. Some people who like numbers in order to make it easier to find when looking at a paper version rather than a machine readable version sometimes skip numbers and only use odd numbers, for example, so they can insert even numbers if needed and preserve the sequence.

Comment: I believe it refers to sequence listings. I know nothing about them. Not sure if the [PCT documentation](https://www.wipo.int/export/sites/www/standards/en/pdf/03-25-01.pdf) could be helpful.

Comment: If that is the question i also have no background to answer.